# Custom TextView slight movements

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` within a `RelativeLayout` and it for some reason makes slight movements to the left and then returns to its original position.  It only happens for a fraction of a second but it is noticeable and annoying. It also seems to happen at random times.

I have no idea what it is but have tried nearly everything.

It is being updated every 200 milliseconds or so with a new character and has lines drawn on the `onDraw()` method.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private LinesView methodView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    ................

    //Set up TextView to display the method
    methodView = (LinesView) v.findViewById(R.id.MC_title);
    methodView.setNumberOfBells(method.getPlayingOn());
    methodView.setTextSize(24);
    methodView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    methodView.setText("           ");
    methodView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    methodView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    methodView.setClickable(false);


    .....................

    public class DisplayMethod extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


    @Override
    protected synchronized Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
           ...........................
     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                methodView.clearText();

                //Ensures the view draws the lines
                methodView.drawLines(true);

                //Sets which bell the user is playing
                methodView.setBell(bellNumberTextViews.get(bellNumberTextViews.size() - 1).getText().toString());


            }
        }); 

           ........................

     //Displays the correct amount of text on screen
    methodView.setLimitingText(method.getPlayingOn(), cText, 6); 


    .........................
        }
  }
```

This is the View I am using

```
public class LinesView extends TextView {

String bell = "2";
int bells;

public boolean lines = false;
Paint paint1 = new Paint();
Paint paint2 = new Paint();

public LinesView(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public LinesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public LinesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setBell(String bell){
    this.bell = bell;
}

public void setNumberOfBells(int bell){
    this.bells = bell;
}

public void clearText(){
    super.setText("");
}

public void setLimitingText(int bells, String text, int lines){

    int characters_allowed = ((bells + 1) * (lines)) - 1;

    if (text.length() > characters_allowed){
        text = text.substring(text.length() - characters_allowed, text.length());
        text = text.substring(1 + text.indexOf("\n"), text.length());
    }

    super.setText(text);
}

public void drawLines(boolean lines){
    this.lines  = lines;
    super.setText(super.getText().toString());
}

public boolean getdrawLines(){
    return lines;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    if (lines){
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setStrokeWidth(8f);
        paint2.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint1.setStrokeWidth(8f);
        paint1.setColor(Color.RED);

        String a = (String) super.getText().toString();

        int index2 = a.indexOf(bell);
        int index1 = a.indexOf("1");

        int next2 = 0;
        int next1 = 0;

        float y = Utils.dpToPx(16, getContext());

        while (a.length() > bells){

            a = a.substring(bells + 1, a.length());

            next2 = a.indexOf(bell);
            next1 = a.indexOf("1");

            if (next2 != -1)
                canvas.drawLine(Utils.dpToPx(6f, getContext()) + index2 * 27f, y - Utils.dpToPx(2, getContext()),
                        Utils.dpToPx(6f, getContext()) + next2 * 27f, y + Utils.dpToPx(27, getContext()), paint2);

            if (next1 != -1)
                canvas.drawLine(Utils.dpToPx(6f, getContext()) + index1 * 27f, y - Utils.dpToPx(2, getContext()),
                         Utils.dpToPx(6f, getContext()) + next1 * 27f, y + Utils.dpToPx(27, getContext()), paint1);

            y = y + Utils.dpToPx(27.6f, getContext());

            index2 = next2;
            index1 = next1;

        }
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

}

Here is the xml layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp" >

    <project.android.bellringing.views.LinesView
        android:id="@+id/MC_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you paste your layout for that `TextView`, and also the `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your `TextView`'s width is `wrap_content`. That means that it will stretch/shrink in function of its content. If you say that every 200 milliseconds your `TextView` is updated, there probably is an instant of time where it has to do a fitting operation.

That's I'd do:

- Change the `layout_width` to `match_parent` and see why is that happening.
- `200` milliseconds (0.2 seconds) is a very low amount of time to see what's actually happening. Try setting it to a bigger delay (say 5000 milliseconds) and see if you can distinguish why it happens.
- If not, try with a debugger and go step-by-step to see what's actually making your `TextView` resize.